# When using a capture card, where is my game displayed?

Tags: streaming

I never used a capture card so my knowledge has gaps so far.

Assuming I plug my console's HDMI cable, which is usually connected to my TV I play on, into the capture card and then plug the capture card into my PC, where will I see the HDMI output?

Will it appear on my PC like a new software/window, which can be opened and played on? Will it replace my usual operating system and I only see the game - as if I plugged in the HDMI into the PC screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, the video would appear in a software on the PC.

More precisely, your PC would detect the capture card as an "input device" (like says, a Webcam).
Then you need a software able to read from this input device and show the output.

Most of the capture cards come with their own software but you can use a generic one (like OBS for instance).

BEWARE : with this kind of setup, there is a big chance that the displayed image will be delayed (which is OK when playing slow paced games likes RPGs but not OK when playing action games).

In that case, you need something called a splitter, which allows to duplicate the video signal.

The idea there would be to send simultaneously the video feed to both PC and TV.
Some cards have splitters integrated, in that case, you just need another cable that goes from the card to your TV/Screen.